# MySQL silly query plan

Tags: mysql

I'm using 5.6.15-56-log Percona Server. Here's my table(which has over 5M records)

```
 CREATE TABLE `promotion_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `template_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,    
  `gain_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
  UNIQUE KEY `index_promotion_codes_on_code` (`code`),    
  KEY `index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id` (`template_id`,`gain_user_id`),    
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5995895 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query 1 (took 0.00 sec, looks fine):

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
    +----+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                           | key                                     | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | ref  | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | 10      | const,const | 33088 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Query 2 (took 4.46 sec, what the hell?)

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id asc limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | index | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  137 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Obviously MySQL did a full table scan so that it took over 4 seconds. And the query time when I force using the index is sane (0.01 sec)

```
select * from promotion_codes use index (index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id) where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id asc limit 1;
```

Query 3 (took 0.09 sec, oh my)

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id desc limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | index | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  138 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The explain result is identical to query 2(order by id asc vs order by id desc), however the time it took is far different.

So I have several questions:

1. Why not use the index when `order by id`, using that index reduces the rows to scan from over 5M to 30K, so there's just no way that MySQL should ignore that index.
2. What does the `rows` column mean in the explain? I always thought it was how many rows MySQL thinks it should scan to get the result, if I'm correct, that in query 2, the `137` is too wrong(the number in query 3 doesn't make sense either).
3. Query 2 happens coz I'm using Rails 4, and when I write something like `Model.where(...).first`, AR will add an `order by primary_key` to the SQL, is there a way to avoid this?

@MarcusAdams, some thoughts on your answer:

1. don't quite agree with you about the query plan

   secondary indexes(`index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id`) already contains primary keys(`id`). So in theory, that `where` & `order by id asc` could be performed with `index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id` only, no need to read any records at all when doing `order by`. So in theory(just in theory), MySQL should read `index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id`, find all that meets the where conditions, then pick the smallest `id`(since there is a `limit 1`, only the smallest one is needed), then use that `id` to retrieve the record. Besides, when `order by id desc`,  the query time is just fine. I'm a bit confused about this, jump to next.
2. MySQL document explains the meaning of `rows` as `The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows.

   I think you are right, there are over 5M records, and about 30K meets the where conditions. If those 30K are distributed equally, then MySQL should only scan couple of hundreds of records before it finds a match, thus saving the `order by` stuff at all.

   And about query 3, now I understand the explain result and query time (compared to query 2). Since those records are located at the 'bottom' of the 5M records(the first match is at 5628309), `order by id desc limit 1` should be really fast coz MySQL should only read a couple of thousands of records(from the last one, in reverse order) before it finds a match.

   Anyway it makes sense to me now :)
3. What I'm trying to say is, when you write `Model.where(...).first`, in Rails 3, the sql would be something like `select * from something limit 1`, while in Rails 4, it becomes `select * from something order by id asc limit 1`, since this `order by id asc` is causing me trouble in this particular case, I'm trying to find a way to avoid this `order by id asc`. Anyway now I know `Model.where(...).take` should do the trick

Comment: With MySQL 5.6, they default to use persistent table stats, which don't get updated as often as we are used to in earlier versions of MySQL. So if you get crazy optimization, first try ANALYZE TABLE to force the stats to refresh. That fixes queries in many cases.

Comment: @BillKarwin it makes sense to me now, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming because you have `SELECT *` above, that you are actually using `SELECT *`.

**1.** If MySQL were to use the `index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id` index when ordering on `id`, then MySQL would have to do the following:

1. Retrieve the primary keys for all 33088 records that match the `WHERE` clause
2. Search for each of the 33088 records using the primary key and read all the table data for the record
3. Order all 33088 records by `id` in a temp table
4. Get the first record

If it were a bubble sort, it would quickly find the first record and could end the sort early, but with the method it uses, it's nearly done sorting before it's sure it has the first record.

Whereas if it uses the primary key (which has the order) it would do the following:

1. Scan the table records in order, following the primary key index
2. Find the first record that matches the WHERE clause (with estimated distribution, about 137 records before it finds one), then stop

**2.** `137` is the estimated number of number of rows it will scan before it finds a match. Total rows divided by 33088 matching records approximately equals 137. Strangely, the EXPLAIN results for the query without an ORDER BY doesn't consider LIMIT (the rows count is the total number of records that match the WHERE), but the query with the ORDER BY does consider the LIMIT (the number it expects to scan before finding one).

**3.** How else would you get the first record?